# How to exclude embeded Tomcat in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot

How can we exclude embedded Tomcat server from Spring Boot application so that we can run that jar on JBoss Server?

Comment: You don't need to exclude it it will just run on the server AND be executable.

Comment: Okay, that means even if we run jar on production server, in our case we are using Jboss on prod,will automatically deploy on jboss instead of Tomcat?

Comment: I was assuming a `war` file and not a `jar` file. You should at least make the dependencies scoped `provided` so that they are moved to a different directory. That directory is used by Spring Boot but not when deploying the file.

Comment: Incase  of jar file what it gonna do, will it deploy on embedded Tomcat or ll it deploy on jboss.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can exclude in pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

You can follow this [link](https://turreta.com/2017/01/10/exclude-embedded-tomcat-in-spring-boot-when-using-thymeleaf/) with screenshots

[Spring documentation on Embedded servlet container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-embedded-web-servers)

Comment: When i run my application with above suggestion, it gives me error "Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown"

Answer (score 10):

you can modify your POM.xml file as follows:

```
  <!-- Removing the dependency for the embedded tomcat -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to mark the tomcat dependency's `scope` as [provided](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope) in your `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `<exclusions>` tag in dependency with `<artificatId>` as 'spring-boot-starter-web'

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

Your final dependency should look like:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Better to mention**

> scope as provided in pom.xml file

**to exclude embedded tomcat server in spring boot maven based application.**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludeGroupIds>org.apache.tomcat.embed</excludeGroupIds>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You can review this article. [Dependency Exclusion](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging.examples.exclude-dependency)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
              <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
              <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
        </exclusions>       
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>        
        <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
              <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
              <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

For Spring Boot 2.7.12 version example is here. If you are using validation don't forget to exclusion from too.
PS: dont copy war file from target folder. it has lib-provided folder. use maven-war-plugin and copy from its output folder.