# Disable features into Spring Boot/Cloud

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm interested is it possible to disable features into Spring Boot/Cloud which are not used?

If there is no way to remove a lot of the necessary features? Do you know some guide how I can make a custom build?

I'm interested how Spring Boot can be optimized for read-time processing.

Comment: can you mention some features which you want to remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude features as [tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47827560/how-to-exclude-embeded-tomcat-in-spring-boot-application) from starter's dependency:

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
>     <exclusions>
>         <exclusion>
>             <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
>             <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
>         </exclusion>
>         <exclusion>
>             <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
>             <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
>         </exclusion>
>         <exclusion>
>             <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
>             <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
>         </exclusion>
>     </exclusions>
> </dependency>
> ```

Or similar for [Logback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984009/disable-logback-in-springboot) by removing from build or classpath:

> Spring Boot tries to work with whatever is in the classpath, so if you don't want logback, take it off the classpath.

> Add exclusion to both the spring-boot-starter and spring-boot-starter-web to resolve the conflict.

Or [cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44486165/how-to-disable-eureka-and-spring-cloud-config-in-a-webmvctest) config/discovery:

> ```
> #Disable discovery
> spring.cloud.discovery.enabled = false    
> #Disable cloud config and config discovery
> spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled = false
> spring.cloud.config.enabled = false
> ```

Answer (score 0):

What are the features are you expecting to disable ?

If you feel any dependency is not used try  tag in your pom.xml. So that you can cut down some dependency and make you application lightweight.